# Unique attribute for each property

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have written an attribute class which I later used for sorting properties.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
class OrderAttribute : Attribute
{
    internal OrderAttribute(int order)
    {
        Order = order;
    }
    public int Order { get; private set; }
}
```

I want this to be unique for class properties, e.g.

Valid scenario

```
[Order(1)]
public string Tier3 { get; set; }

[Order(2)]
public string Tier4 { get; set; }
```

Invalid Scenario since value "1" is repeated.

```
[Order(1)]
public string Tier3 { get; set; }

[Order(1)]
public string Tier4 { get; set; }
```

PS: Attribute values can be repeated for different class properties but not in same. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not possible at compile time; you would need to check when sorting.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay thanks for the suggestion. That's the work around I am using but unfortunately that does lot's of time consuming operation and just fails in the end. I wish Reflection would have supported this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although attribute values can be repeated, there's no easy way supported to make sure they are unique (they are run time only), you would need to check when actually sorting as Johnathan has already mentioned. There are ways around this, but is it worth it in the long run? A few options I can think of are:

1. Hook into the actual build process, create a build task that uses reflection to check and fail if needed.
2. Run a post-build (post build event) step that loads your dll and reflects on those attribute types.
3. Create a possible rule that will check for uniqueness.

There may be other ways, but these are the one's I could think of at the moment.

Comment: I feel option 2 is feasible for me. Thanks for the effort Sir :)\

Comment: @Imad You're welcome, I've done both post build and used FXCop to create a rule before. Post build isn't too bad and is easier IMHO in this case than writing a custom rule.